# Async code splitting in webpack and typescript

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, webpack

In webpack 2.2 one can use async code splitting using `import().then()` (https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-async/).I cannot get it to work with typescript. I've got compilation errors.
How do I fix it?

Comment: Can you post your code and what compilation errors you get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Async Code Splitting** (or Lazy Loading) is being defined as standard by **TC39** (https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import).

Async Code Splitting is now supported by [TypeScript 2.4](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript). It's a feature called **Dynamic Import Expressions**.

```
import (/* webpackChunkName: "momentjs" */ "moment")
    .then((moment) => {
         // lazyModule has all of the proper types, autocomplete works,
         // type checking works, code references work \o/
         const time = moment().format();
         console.log(time);
     })
     .catch((err) => {
         console.log("Failed to load moment", err);
     });
```

Take into account you must use "module": "esnext" in tsconfig.json.
Take a look to this post for further information: https://blog.josequinto.com/2017/06/29/dynamic-import-expressions-and-webpack-code-splitting-integration-with-typescript-2-4/

If you are using TypeScript < 2.4, there is a known work around:

```
interface System {
  import<T> (module: string): Promise<T>
}

declare var System: System

import * as lazyModule from './lazy-loaded-file'

System.import<typeof lazyModule>('./lazy-loaded-file')
.then(lazyModule => {
  // lazyModule has all of the proper types, autocomplete works,
  // type checking works, code references work \o/
})
// the './lazy-loaded-file' static import is only used for its types so typescript deletes it
// result: type-checked code splitting with lazy loading
```

From the **source**: https://gist.github.com/Kovensky/e2ceb3b9715c4e2ddba3ae36e9abfb05

I did an **example** (webpack 2, React, TypeScript) using that code lazy loading the library momentjs, you can find here:

https://github.com/jquintozamora/react-typescript-webpack2-cssModules-postCSS/blob/master/app/src/components/AsyncLoading/AsyncLoading.tsx#L47